# Possible to prevent others from account creation when using Firebase Email/Password authentication?

Tags: firebase-authentication

I would like to add users only manually to my project. Now I realized when using the Email/Password sign-in method everyone with my `firebaseConfig` could use `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` to create new users.

Is there any way to use a method which allows only me to add new users?

I ask this because there will be some infos I wanted to make available in the database for all my added users. This would be easy to do with a rule like this: `".read": "auth != null"`. But when everyone can create a user account I have to create a list with all allowed uids of users and nest this infos I want to make available inside every single uid entry...

One possible workaround I can think of would be that I manually create the users with a faked up email address always with the same domain. And then make the infos available only to this email domains with a security rule like this:

```
{
 “rules”: {
 “.read”: “auth.token.email.endsWith(‘@example.com’)”
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have found a way to only allow manually created users which are created by myself in the Firebase console.

In Authentication > Settings > User action > Enable create (sign-up)

I can simply deactivate this setting.

[image]